# Foreach loops only through the last column of the table (ES6)

Tags: javascript, search, filter, foreach, jquery-selectors

I was trying to build my first search function for a phonelist. Unfortunately it looks like, my filter function loops only trough the last column of the table. 
Did i miss something? Or do i have to use a different approach for this?

*PS: Pardon for the possible duplicate. All examples that i've found has been for PHP.*

Many thanks in advance!

```js
const phonelist = document.querySelector('table');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('#search');
const searchResult = document.querySelector('#search-result');
const searchValue = document.querySelector('#search-value');

// EVENTS
function initEvents() {
  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', filter);
}

function filter(e) {
  let text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  console.log(text);

  // SHOW SEARCH-RESULT DIV
  if (text != '') {
    searchValue.textContent = text;
    searchResult.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    searchResult.classList.add('hidden');
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((row) => {
    let item = row.textContent.toLowerCase();

    if (item.indexOf(text) != -1) {
      row.parentElement.style.display = 'table-row';
      console.log(row.parentElement);
    } else {
      row.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
}

// ASSIGN EVENTS
initEvents();
```

```html
<input id="search" />

<div class="phonelist">
  <div id="search-result" class="hidden">
    <p>Search results for <b id="search-value"></b>:</p>
  </div>
  <table class="striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Fax</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>165</td>
        <td>516</td>
        <td>1.47</td>
        <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>443</td>
        <td>516</td>
        <td>1.47</td>
        <td>Jane Dow</td>
        <td>Development</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are querying the wrong element

```
  document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((row) => {
```

I think you want to be querying the row

```
  document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((row) => {
```

otherwise you are of overriding your class changes with whatever is the result of the last column

(and obviously apply the class on the tr and not the parent of the tr)

Comment: @Toharawk couple of extra points:
- you would usually look at filtering the results against the data directly and then render your table rather than manipulating the dom directly (less to render and js is faster than dom manipulation
- for what you're doing the answer of AvcS is probably better as querying the TR then the TD of the row and looping through those will give you more control/granularity for you test than just the text (like classes attributes etc)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually going through all the elements but the changes from last column are overriding changes from previous columns.

Let's say you searched for `dow`, 2nd row 4th column is matched and shows the parent but after that your loop goes to 2nd row 5th column which doesn't match and hides the parent row.

I have updated your code, as shown below you should loop through the rows, check if any of its columns are matching and update the row only once based on the result.

```js
const phonelist = document.querySelector('table');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('#search');
const searchResult = document.querySelector('#search-result');
const searchValue = document.querySelector('#search-value');

// EVENTS
function initEvents() {
  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', filter);
}

function filter(e) {
  let text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  console.log(text);

  // SHOW SEARCH-RESULT DIV
  if (text != '') {
    searchValue.textContent = text;
    searchResult.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    searchResult.classList.add('hidden');
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => {
    let foundMatch = false;

    row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(col => {
      let item = col.textContent.toLowerCase();
      foundMatch = foundMatch || item.indexOf(text) > -1;
    });

    if (foundMatch) {
      row.style.display = 'table-row';
    } else {
      row.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

// ASSIGN EVENTS
initEvents();
```

```html
<input id="search" />

<div class="phonelist">
  <div id="search-result" class="hidden">
    <p>Search results for <b id="search-value"></b>:</p>
  </div>
  <table class="striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Fax</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>165</td>
        <td>516</td>
        <td>1.47</td>
        <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>443</td>
        <td>516</td>
        <td>1.47</td>
        <td>Jane Dow</td>
        <td>Development</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```